# How to poplulate a tuple list, preserving its structure in Python using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, arraylist

I have a list

```
form.country.choices = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2')]
```

I need to populate this List preserving its structure till 100.

i.e

```
form.country.choices = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3').....('100', '100')]
```

I tried

```
newlist = []
for x in range(10):
    innerlist = []
for y in range(1,100):
    innerlist.append(y)
    newlist.append(innerlist)
print(newlist)
```

This doesn't work.

I want to preserve the structure. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension, iterating over stringified numbers from 1 to 100:

```py
res = [(n, n) for n in map(str, range(1,101))]
```

Output:

```py
[('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ..., ('98', '98'), ('99', '99'), ('100', '100')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful for you:

```
l=[]
for i in range(1,101):
   l.append((str(i),str(i)))
```

Output will be:

```
[('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3').....('100', '100')]
```

Comment: We can easily make range number 101

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [(str(i),str(i)) for i in range(0,101)]
```

output

```
[('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3').....('100', '100')]
```